# How to combine or merge two arrays in the result of foreach in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not that good in arrays so maybe someone can help me on how to format my array in to a single array.

**Result of a foreach**

```
Array
(
 [0] => name1
 [1] => name2
)
Array
(
 [0] => name3
 [1] => name4
)
```

**Attempted Code**

```
foreach($groups as $key => $usernames)
{
   print_r($usernames['usernames']);
   foreach($usernames['usernames'] as $key2 => $val)
   {
     print_r($val); //But this will give me name1name2name3name4
     $names[] = $val; //Will give me Array([0] => name1name2name3name4)
      //^^ Right here is my answer. LOL
   }
}
```

**Expected format**

```
Array
(
  [0] => name1
  [1] => name2
  [2] => name3
  [3] => name4
)
```

Comment: whats the array names of first two arrays? Do you get it when you loop `$groups` ?

Comment: In result of foreach, if  its two different arrays then you can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function of php

Comment: Yes @IdentityUnkn0wn

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$names` hasn't been declared beforehand, and the `[]` is concatenating the `$val` to the end of it like a character array.

Try adding before your whole code:

```
$names = [];
```

Comment: I do that because I want to store the result in a new array.